# Winform listview ColumnWidthChanging event does not trigger in Windows Server OS

Tags: c#, .net, events

I added a listview in my winform application using .NET 4.8 Framework.
I added a ColumnWidthChanging event to disable the user from adjusting column widths and it works as expected in Windows 10.

But when I tried to run my application in Windows Server 2016, the event does not trigger. I added logging to determine if the event was called and no logs were written.

**MainForm.cs**

```
private void listView_Counters_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewWidth = this.listView_Counters.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
        logger.Info("Column Width: " + e.NewWidth.ToString());

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

**MainForm.Designer.cs**

```
// 
// listView_Counters
// 
this.listView_Counters.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
resources.ApplyResources(this.listView_Counters, "listView_Counters");
this.listView_Counters.HideSelection = false;
this.listView_Counters.Name = "listView_Counters";
this.listView_Counters.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.listView_Counters.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
this.listView_Counters.ColumnWidthChanging += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangingEventHandler(this.listView_Counters_ColumnWidthChanging);
```

Is this a limitation in Windows Server OS? Or is there another way to do ColumnWidthChanging event?

I appreciate all the help and ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Server windows** usually have many access restrictions that other regular windows do not have.
You can usually solve the problem of writing and accessing users and software by setting access levels in the folder of the running project and setting access to the files to be written to.

Comment: Hello, actually there is no problem with access. My application runs without major issues. My only problem is just that I noticed that I can still change the width of the listview columns and upon debugging, it turns out that the ColumnWidthChanging event was never triggered